# Calling subclass methods - Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, class, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working through the 'Learning Cocos2d' book, and I'm stuck on something basic.

So, theres a parent Class: GameplayLayer. In it, there's an 'init' method which creates an instance of the main character in here - 'Viking'. Viking is a subclass of 'GameCharacter', which is a subclass of 'GameObject'.

```
        #pragma mark INIT PLAYER
        Viking *viking = [[Viking alloc] 
        initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
        spriteFrameByName:@"viking.png"]];

        [viking setJoystick:leftJoystick];
        [viking setFireButton:fireButton];
        [viking setSecondaryButton:secondaryButton];
        [viking setCollisionLayer:collidableLayer]; // send collision layer to player
        [viking setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width * 0.35f, screenSize.height * 0.14f)];
        [viking setHealth:100];

        [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:viking z:1000 tag:kPlayerSpriteTagValue];
```

Now, Viking has an update method which is called every frame by GameplayLayer. It's parent class, GameObject also has this update method, which brings up an error message if it is accidentally called - "GameObject update should be overridden'.

So in my code, I'm calling the update method of 'Viking' with the following method:

```
    #pragma mark UPDATE_METHOD
-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime
{
    CCArray *listOfGameObjects = 
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode children];
    for (GameObject *tempChar in listOfGameObjects) {
        CCLOG(@"engine found %@",tempChar);
        [tempChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:deltaTime
 andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];
    }

}
```

So, this is supposed to call the 'updateStateWithDeltaTime' method in Viking. But somehow, it's calling the parent method in GameObject which says 'updatestate should be overridden'. How do I override the parent method?

Many thanks,

Carl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to cast `tempChar` to a `Viking`.

```
    for (GameObject *tempChar in listOfGameObjects) 
    {
        [(Viking *) tempChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:deltaTime
 andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];
    }
```

Because you're doing a for loop with fast enumeration of `GameObjects`, the local variable assumes that all objects are `GameObjects`. You need to explicitly cast `tempChar` to a `Viking` so that the program knows which class to look for the method in.

As an interesting side note, if `GameObject` didn't have the same method as `Viking` did, you would be getting a warning in XCode telling you it couldn't find the method you're asking for (because it needs to know that every object this could be called on has it).

You might want to check that the object you're calling this on is the correct class (if you only want to call this on `Viking` objects). You'd add `if ([GameObject isKindOfClass[Viking class])` above your update method call.

Comment: Hey thanks @Dustin! I hate to say, but in my case the error turned out to be a total schoolboy error. Viking's update method had a typo in an instance var! Doh! But you've provided me with some useful syntax with 'isKindOfClass[Viking class]' which I shall use! My tip - when debugging, don't forget to check the obvious!

Comment: This is completely wrong. The whole point of "overriding" is that when the method is called on the object, the method from the most specific subclass is called. It is irrelevant what the static type of the expression you call it on is.

Comment: @newacct When I saw this question I thought the problem was that he was calling a `GameObject` when he thought he was calling a `Viking`. OP said the parent method was being called, and if he was calling a subclass's method correctly that would not be happening. With what turned out to be his problem that's not the case. Feel free to post your own answer or edit mine, but the problem has been resolved.

Comment: @Dustin: but my point is, under no circumstance would casting `tempChar` to `Viking *` before calling the method be a useful suggestion for this problem. Casting object pointer types does not do anything at runtime; it is a purely compile-time construct that helps the compiler do static type checking. Since the method can already be called without the cast, adding the cast does not have any effect on the code at all.

Comment: @newacct, you're right. I was thinking that it would perhaps cause a narrowing class conversion error if wrong class was being called so that there would be concrete evidence for `GameObject` being called when `Viking` was supposed to be as the superclass's method can't be called from the subclass. That's why I added the class check code at the end.